# UIAutomation (core) is very negatively impacted by multiple User32.FindWindow calls

Tags: c#, pinvoke, ui-automation

I am getting much closer to figuring this out and primarily posting to share my results.

What I am seeing is that a couple calls to User32.FindWindow (on the same window) will screw up a calls to UI Automation core methods such as FindAllBuildCache().

Does anyone know if there is a proper way to dispose of the handles you get back from a PInvoke FindWindow call?

Comment: please show some code. Sounds a lot like the first not leave the playground untouched. Do they work in reverse order? if they do that's definitely the problem if they don't it might be that they both need to clean up

Comment: Unlike Kernel HANDLEs (which represent things like Files and shared sections and mutexes, and which need to be Close'd when a process is done with them), Windows handles - HWNDs (usually IntPtr in managed) - don't need disposing; the handle is shared across all process on the desktop and is valid so long as the target HWND is present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BrendanMcKless,

Thanks for pointing that out.  That is good information to have.

Now I am 99% sure that the issue I encountered was due to using the UIAutomationCore at the same time as the AutomationClient.  The Core I am using by having a tlbimp build step to create a managed assembly from the Core DLL.  I get better performance using the Core, and also get a pattern called IUIAutomationLegacyIAccessiblePattern, which enables me to get the cell contents from an Infragistics Ultragrid.  I noticed yesterday that even if I don't use the AutomationClient, my test begins to encounter problems as soon as the assembly is loaded:

I see this in the output window when I create an instance of a class with AutomationClient imports:

```
Loaded UIAutomationClientsideProviders.dll
Loaded Accessibility.dll
```

The problem could be the Accessibility.dll because I am using IUIAutomationLegacyIAccessiblePattern, but that DLL is being loaded as a dependency of UIAutomationClientsideProviders.dll anyways so....

I'll update my post if the solution doesn't turn out to be correct (I have a significant amount of rework to do before I can be 100% sure).

---

Added a while later:

The problem was definitely using the UI Automation Core along with the managed client side UI Automation stuff.  What a pain!

Comment: Note that accessibilty.dll must be a managed wrapper for the Active Accessibly stuff which is in OLEACC.DLL.